# Trying to split audio into 20ms chunks and making a spectrogram but its looking weird

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, spectrogram

I basically have this audio file that is `16-bit PCM WAV mono at 44100hz` and I'm trying to convert it into a spectrogram. But I want a spectrogram of the audio every 20ms (Trying this for speech recognition), but whenever I try to compare what I have to Audacity, its really different. I'm kind of new to python so I was trying to base this off of my java knowledge. Any help would be appreciated. I think I'm either splitting the read samples incorrectly (What I did was split it every 220 elements in the array since I believe Audio Data is just samples in the time domain to get it to 20ms audio)

Here's the code I have right now:

```
import librosa.display
import numpy

audioPath = 'C:\\Users\\pawar\\Desktop\\Resister.wav'

audioData, sampleRate = librosa.load(audioPath, sr=None)
print(sampleRate)
new = numpy.zeros(shape=(220, 1))

counter = 0
for i in range(0, len(audioData), 882):
    new = (audioData[i: i + 882])
    STFT = librosa.stft(new, n_fft=882)
    print(type(STFT))
    audioDatainDB = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(STFT))
    
    print(type(audioDatainDB))
    librosa.display.specshow(audioDatainDB, sr=sampleRate, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz')
    #plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    plt.show()
    counter += 1
    print("Your local debug print statement ", counter)
```

As for the values, well I was playing around with them quite a bit trying to get it to work. Doesn't seem to be of any luck ;/

Here's the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVntx.png

And here's what Audacity shows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIGy8.png

I know its not 20ms in the audacity one but you can see the two don't look even a bit similar